# Using ToString to reformat a numeric field in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, tostring

I have a LINQ query which creates an anonymous collection.  One thing I'm returning is a number, which I'd like formatted as currency instead of 50.23888838222 etc.  However if I try something like:

```
... select new { Amount = e.Item_Amount.ToString("C") }
```

I get told 'No overload for .ToString takes 1 arguments.

However this code works fine elsewhere when changing an individual string.

I've had issues like this with Linq to Sql and understand why, but this is just an in memory collection.  What's the best way to achieve this end?

Thanks

Comment: What type is `Item_Amount` of?

Comment: It was a nullable decimal, sorry for leaving that fact out guys.  Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its `nullable` field (Maybe).

```
 Amount = e.Item_Amount.Value.ToString("C")
 //or
 Amount = (e.Item_Amount ?? 0).ToString("C");
```

Comment: In this case there would be `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Matej - Test this code :  decimal? val =  (decimal?) 10.10; string str=val.ToString("C");

Comment: Doesn't necessarily mean it's a nullable type, a string would throw the same exception (No overload for...)

Comment: May be! I guess from this - " One thing I'm returning is a **number**..".

Comment: He could mean returning a number stored in a string type. It's a possibility :-)

Comment: Hi AVD - very perceptive, I hadn't even thought of that.  It was indeed a nullable decimal, and your coalescing operator did the trick perfectly.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like e.Item_Amount is not of a numeric type.

You can either change its type to a numeric type such as Int32 or decimal (preferable) or to parse the values during iteration.

```
select new { 
  Amount = decimal.Parse(e.Item_Amount).ToString("C") 
}
```

If your dealing with a nullable type, you could do the following:

```
select new { 
      Amount = (e.Item_Amount ?? 0).ToString("C") 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that Vince.  As it turns out it was a nullable decimal as you'd noted in the second part of your answer.